# Console FireBAse INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android

I have an Android application that works very well on Android 10 API 29 and I have changed to Android API 34 or 33. But I still get the error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED.
Can you tell me where the error could be in my manifest?

here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="company.com.infotainerApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:name="company.com.infotainerApp.views.activity.myCustomApp"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="company.com.infotainerApp.views.activity.Company"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="company.com.infotainerApp.tasks.ApiService">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- REGISTER TO RECEIVE EVENTS -->
                <action android:name ="broadcast.ApiService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="company.com.infotainerApp.service.ScannerForegroundService"
            android:stopWithTask="true"/>

        <service android:name="company.com.infotainerApp.tasks.CompanyService"
            android:stopWithTask="true"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my Build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


def keystorePropertiesFile = file("release-keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 11
def versionCodes = 11

if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    println 'Load keystore properties from local file'
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
} else {
    println 'Load keystore file not exist'
    try {
        keystoreProperties['keyAlias'] = System.getenv('KEY_ALIAS')
        keystoreProperties['keyPassword'] = System.getenv('KEY_PASSWORD')
        keystoreProperties['storePassword'] = System.getenv('KEYSTORE_PASSWORD')
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new GradleException("Please add release-keystore.properties OR set environment variables KEY_ALIAS, KEY_PASSWORD & KEYSTORE_PASSWORD to supply the credentials for signing.")
    }
}

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('keyStores\\Upload-keystore.jks')
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['KEY_ALIAS']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['KEY_PASSWORD']
            storePassword keystoreProperties['KEYSTORE_PASSWORD']
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion '34'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "company.Infotainer.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode versionCodes
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
        //or soede
        archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //signingConfig debug.signingConfig //we use the signing config for Debug to generate the Release Version for the app
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'cc.duduhuo.util:digest-util:1.1.1'

}
```

I tried to run a robo test on Console Firebase to test my application with the new SDK and I get this error every time

Comment: applicationId "company.Infotainer.app"
package="company.com.infotainerApp" should be the same?

Comment: i got the Solution 

The fix for these errors is to add the attribute android:exported to any <activity>, <activity-alias>,<service>, or <receiver> components that have <intent-filter>s declared in the app’s AndroidManifest.xml file.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lets-be-explicit-about-our-intent-filters-c5dbe2dbdce0